# Problem defining the height of an element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I'm trying to run the following code on a website to set up the height of elements in a webpage:

```
document.querySelector("#body").style.height = window.innerHeight - document.querySelector("#footer").offsetHeight;
```

It's part of a function, and all the other parts of the function appear to be working properly, but this section does not work.

A similar command however, written with jQuery, does work:

```
$("#body").css({ "height" : window.innerHeight - document.querySelector("#footer").offsetHeight });
```

But I'd rather not have to call on the jQuery library for something as small as this.

Any suggestions as for what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to append 'px' at the end of the computed value.

```
(window.innerHeight - document.querySelector("#footer").offsetHeight) + 'px'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the `#body` element have a `style` attribute?
If it does not it may be that nothing is set, jQuery does not need the style to be present to change it using the `css` function

Comment: Yes, #body has a css height of 100%, and the result is that #footer gets pushed off the bottom of the screen.